# What exactly is power? And what limits its generation?

Tags: power, power-generation

I know that P=I*V, and that when power is constant then current is inversely proportional to voltage. In case of transformers, stepping down voltage increases current. I was told that this because of the law of conservation of energy, as you can't create power from nothing.

My first question is, why is electric power defined like that? How does Ohm's law hold in transmission lines where power is constant?

Also, when power is generated, what limits the amount generated? How much of generated power is in terms of voltage and current?

Comment: TLDR: Power is energy per unit time. One Watt is one Joule per Second. That's why "conservation of energy" is part of the answer.

Comment: Well, an ant isn't going to power-up a movie cinema by running on a treadmill. Similarly, you're not going to wind the generator with windings as slender as the hairs on your head.

"Quantity of stuff" - is one of the things that affects quantity of power generated. Niagra falls creates an awful lot more power than anything you or I could eve get a hold of.

Comment: Power is the derivative of energy wrt time. So power is not inherently limited like energy is, but there are practical limits. For example, a fiber laser might produce peak power of tens of kW but operate from a wall plug, because the power is produced in brief pulses at a low duty cycle, so the average power is reasonable. The current record for man-made peak power is held by China's Superintense Ultrafast laser facility at 5.3 PW.

Answer (score 3):

> My first question is, why is electric power defined like that?

Because a device that consumes \$I\$ amperes of current at \$V\$ volts can do *up to* \$V * I\$ joules of useful thermodynamic work every second while consuming \$V * I\$ joules of energy per second. The difference is losses as heat and other undesired forms of energy (e.g. a tiny amount as sound).

There is a physics justification underpinning this: In the simple resistive dissipation case, the voltage drop is the difference in the scalar electric potential, i.e. \$\int\vec{E}\cdot d\vec l\$, across the load in question. Each electron does work of \$q_{e0} \cdot V\$ it passes through the load, and you can algebraically transform this to yield joules per coulomb, and then finally relate watts to volts and amperes.

In the case of a resistor, all the power is turned to heat (which may radiate away).

> how does ohm's law hold in transmission lines where power is constant?

Ohm's Law holds in the sense that the voltage *drop* on the transmission line is equal to the current times the resistance of the transmission line. By Kirchoff's Voltage Law, the total input voltage must equal the tx line voltage drop + the voltage drop across the load.

In an ideal scenario, we have most of the voltage drop across the load (e.g. a 120 V output from the transformer is dropped as 1 or 2 V in the wiring and 118 or 119 V in whatever device you are trying to power).

> Also, when power is generated, what limits the amount generated?

Every device has limits on the voltage and current it can withstand. Too much voltage, and you can have insulation breakdown, arcing, etc. Too much current and you may overheat and melt parts. This puts a limit on the power that it can handle.

Furthermore, conservation of energy still applies. Even if I have a generator which is *rated* for 10 kW attached to a set of bicycle pedals, I won't be able to do 10 kJ of work per second on the pedals. I might be able to produce around 1 kW at best, and that's the most that an electric load will be able to get when attached to the human-powered generator and I'm pedaling it. If I had a gasoline engine powering the generator, I'll find that the fuel consumption would need to increase as the electrical load increases.

> how much of generated power is in terms of voltage and current?

This question does not make sense. All power is a product of voltage *and* current. Lots of current at minimal voltage (e.g. in a low-resistance or superconducting load) dissipates very little power, and lots of voltage with microscopic current (e.g. a good insulator) also dissipates very little power.